# How to avoid republishing language folders when using Ajax Control Toolkit for ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using the Ajax Control Toolkit for ASP.NET.

Whenever I make a change in my code (**that has nothing to do with the Ajax control**) and republish a project, it seems all the language folders of the Ajax control toolkit are republished UNNECESSARILY.

How do I avoid this? And are these folders necessary at all in the first place if my page is in English only?

```
2>Publishing folder bin/ar...
2>Publishing folder bin/cs...
2>Publishing folder bin/de...
2>Publishing folder bin/es...
2>Publishing folder bin/fr...
2>Publishing folder bin/he...
2>Publishing folder bin/hi...
2>Publishing folder bin/it...
```

Comment: possible dupe: [MS Visual Studio: How to exclude certain Project Folders from publishing? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104818/ms-visual-studio-how-to-exclude-certain-project-folders-from-publishing)

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

simply if you are not using them in your development, delete them all and just keep the one that you are using, I remember doing that, just copying what I really used

side note: I recommend stop using the ajax control toolkit because it is not recommended by microsoft any more long time ago and event microsoft officially stopped using it and used instead jquery