# Exclude folder from project before build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project with multiples folders in it, and I'm trying to exclude one of these folders with a pre-build event from the final build.

My architecture:

```
Project.Client
|General
| | classes to build
|Entities
| | classes to exclude from the build
| Helpers
| | classes to build
```

For now I found this command, but it's not really working...

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
rmdir Entities
```

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to select the classes in that folder in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and set their build action to "None" in the Properties window.

Comment: This solution is "working", but it's not the ideal one... Classes in the folder are automatically generated by my model (CodeFluent)

Comment: It would be great if one would be able to set the build action for an entire folder, sadly, I don't see that option. [There has been a similar question which might help you though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104818/ms-visual-studio-how-to-exclude-certain-project-folders-from-publishing)