# ASP.NET Core Publish Exclude Folder (or .json files)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, publish, asp.net-core-2.1, webdeploy

I have an asp core 2.1 project, and I'm trying to publish via web deploy.

I have a folder called "Angular" and inside that are my source files (including some .json files for angular's config) - these get built (via a separate process "ng build") into the wwwroot/app directory ready for publish. As such, I want NOTHING from this Angular directory to end up on the published folder. But I still want the Angular folder to show up in the project / solution explorer / find in files.

At present, it is publishing the Angular folder with all .json files inside. Obviously this is bad and I need to stop this from happening. I'm pretty sure this is happening because of this...
https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/dev/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L32

I am publishing using the following command:

```
dotnet publish C:\blah\ -c Release /p:PublishProfile=WebDeployProfile
```

(and also sometimes doing it via the Visual Studio Publish using the same profile, but less frequently - I notice that these function differently, which I find odd)

I have tried so many different things, both in the .csproj and .pubxml, it's getting ridiculous, and I currently believe msbuild/deploy is a total mess, and quite broken.

I am hoping someone can help me with what should be a supremely simple and easy thing to accomplish - exclude a folder from publish (whilst leaving it in the project).

Answer (score 23):

I ran into the same issue.

I had a folder that included multiple json files that the publish process picked up and sent to the publish output.

For excluding a folder such as 'FolderYouDontWant' add the following to your .csproj file:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="FolderYouDontWant\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you have specific files you are looking for to exclude rather than whole folders, use the exact file path such as:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="FolderWithFile\dont-want.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you have multiple paths you can add all of the Content elements to the same *ItemGroup*.

Comment: This worked for me using RIDER with ASP Net Core, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your .csproj file starting with "appsettings" all "appsettings.test" etc. remove publish file

```
  <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="appsettings*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" /> 
      </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Pls add some description/explanation to your answer and explain how it works and solves the problem.

Comment: your .csproj file  starting with "appsettings" all "appsettings.test" etc. remove publish  file

Answer (score 0):

Here are changes to the project (.csproj) file to exclude folders/files from being published. This was tested on a .NET Core 6 project with VS 2022.

To remove a directory:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="FolderToRemove\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

To remove an individual file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="SomeFolder\file.txt" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

To add a file back from the directory removed:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="FolderToRemove\file-to-add-back.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```